# Laravel sql queries on 3rd relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to show all users who have a permission name of "Manager"

I have the following databases

> users (many to many relationship with roles) | id: int
>
> role_user (pivot table) | role_id: int user_id:int
>
> roles (many to many relationship with users and has many relationship
>   with permissions ) | id:int
>
> permissions (belongs to roles) | id:int name:string

Can someone please point me in right direction of how to compose the query, I'm using laravel 5.2 but happy for raw sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw sql will look like:

```
select * from users 
inner join role_user on users.id=role_user.user_id
inner join roles on role_user.role_id=roles.id
inner join permissions on roles.id=permissions.role_id
where permissions.name='Manager'
group by users.id
```

Comment: Perfect, I recoded to make it more laravel

$managerUsers= DB::table('users')
            ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
            ->join('roles ', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
            ->join('permissions ', 'roles.id', '=', 'permissions.role_id')
            ->where('permissions.name', '=', 'manager')
            ->get();

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent's query builder offers **whereHas()** method that allows filtering on attributes of related models. It supports nested relations as well, so the following should do the trick:

```
$managers = User::whereHas('roles.permissions', function($query) {
  $query->where('name', '=', 'Manager');
})->get();
```